# New order with wrong time

Tags: orders, email, timezone

When i created an order, the server will send out a new order email, but the order time was wrong. The time created in the email template  {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}} is displayed at CST time (GMT - 8), i have to make the time GMT+8, how can i do that?

Comment: Can anyone help this??

Comment: Are you sure, your server time is set as UTC, +8 and -8 looks like a problem with your server time.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the definition for this Model's method, I see:

```
public function getCreatedAtFormated($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, true);
}
```

I note that it's calling $this->getCreatedAtStoreDate() to basically get the date.  This suggests that it's giving you a date relative to a given store.  Having a look at the General Tab in the Admin's config, I notice that you can set different timezones for websites that would presumably affect the store you are dealing with.  Are you sure you have customized that how you want to?

Comment: already set my timezone, but not work